# lib location for non-default gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, installation

Where is the canonical place on Linux to install a library, that was not compiled with the standard system compiler? /us/local/lib or /usr/local/mylib-1.0-gcc.version? Some place else? The same library compiled with the system gcc may be installed and used, too.

Background:
I am on CentOS 6.5. The standard compiler is gcc 4.4. I have a closed source program, that is compiled on CentOS 6.0 with gcc 4.1.2 (strange enough, gcc is also 4.4 there). I want to build a plugin for the program that uses a (open source) library. So I compile gcc 4.1.2 and the library with gcc 4.1.2. Where does the library go?

Comment: What incompatibility between gcc-4.1 and gcc-4.4 justifies going through all this trouble?

Comment: I don't know, the documentation specifically states, that plugins with another gcc version will NOT work.